# dotless build task error

Tags: build, dotless

After recently upgrading to the latest version of dotless on nuget, I'm now getting build errors.

I have dotless set up as a build task, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/2181543/435460

It used to work, but when I recently updated to the latest version on nuget I now receive the error `dotless 1.3.0.5 has stopped working` when I attempt to build, resulting in my build failing.

Is there a way to get this working again?  I've already done some preliminary google investigating and have come up short.

Comment: If you compile using the exe outside the build process, what happens?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this was caused on our machines by something removing the .NET 3.5 Framework - the dev had been having other issues, and I think removed 4.5, and something around that cleaned out 3.5 next time he rebooted.

Re-installing .NET 3.5 seemed to have resolved the issue.